# PCL application hanged when computing tracker

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library

I am properly setting .pcd file target, getting pointCloud from sensor and its downsampled pointCloud (about 40000 points but also tried with less). However, once executing `tracker_->compute();` viewer is hanged and also debugger keeps waiting without throwing any error. 
Pcd has 1.92Mb, proper format and segmented... Any idea about which could be the problem? I am using Visual C++ 2013 and PCL 1.7.2.

```
tracker_->setInputCloud(cloud_pass_downsampled_); 
tracker_->compute();
```